# using post method in ajax with perl script & parameters

Tags: javascript, ajax, perl, parameters

I'm trying to use POST method in XMLHTTPRequest by calling Perl script with parameters.
These variables (uName, uProject,etc) are valid I checked.  write.pl also works when I manually pass parameters from command line.
However, the parameters are coming up as blank when passing.  Please help.

```
request.open("POST", "/cgi-bin/write.pl", true);
var params = uName + " " + uProject +" " + uSVAC + " " + uEVAC + " " + uLevel;
alert (params);
request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
request.send(params);
```

Comment: is your cgi-bin directory really in the same path as your HTML?

Answer (score 1):

You are separating your parameters with a space (" "). x-www-form-urlencoded says they must be separated with an ampersand `&`, and any special characters within the values must be encoded (space to `%20`, ampersand to `%26`, etc). You also need to provide names to your parameters.

Such as

```
var params = 'uName=' + uname + '&uProject=' + uProject + '&uSVAC=' + uSVAC +
 '&uEVAC=' + uEVAC + '&uLevel=' + uLevel;
```